# Jboss(Wildfly) server log not able to print MDC key value using %X{key}

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly-8

I have configured **%X{key}** pattern in standalone.xml file(at path /usr/local/wildfly/standalone/configuration) under logging module as given below.

```
<formatter name="PATTERN">
   <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %X{user-identity} %s%E%n"/>
</formatter>
<formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
    <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %X{user-identity} %s%E%n"/>
 </formatter>
```

Where user-identity is key which is set in ContainerRequestFilter implementation class like MDC.put("user-identity", "123"). and MDC is Mapped Diagnostic Context in jboss logging.

Same code is working for Development server(i.e. printing user-identity value in server.log file) but not working in QA or Production environment.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem just by configuring **%X{key}** pattern in standalone-full.xml file(at path /usr/local/wildfly/standalone/configuration) under logging module configuration under PATTERN and COLOR-PATTERN formatter.